# RobotFramework file .save() function changes format

Tags: python, robotframework, abstract-syntax-tree

I have been coding in Robotframework and Python:
I use get_model() to get model from a .robot file. Then modify, the model using ModelTransformer() which works on the basic idea of AST(Abstract Syntax Trees).

But after finishing the modification, when I try to save the modified model into a new **.robot file** using **.save() function**, this completely changes the format of the new robot file.

```
# Code to save new robot file
model.save("New.robot")
```

Can anyone please let me know, how to solve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by it completely changes the format of the new robot file?

Comment: It basically doesn't maintain the structure which it has to. The AST structure.